# Google Code Scan: Wait for QR code scan to complete

Tags: android, kotlin, async-await, google-play-services, google-mlkit

I am trying to integrate [Google code scanner](https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/vision/barcode-scanning/code-scanner#kotlin) into my Android app.

Calling

```
Tasks.await(scanner.startScan()).rawValue ?: ""
```

where `scanner` is the `GmsBarcodeScanner` object
throws

```yaml
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Must not be called on the main application thread
```

But Google code scanner brings up the camera on the entire screen covering anything underneath.
So where's the problem if my app's UI becomes unresponsive while the QR Code is being scanned?

Will `await()` prevent the QR Code scanner from launching? If so, *why?*

I need to stop to get the results before I can proceed.

Comment: Please read the question carefully.
"Google code scanner brings up the camera on the entire screen covering anything underneath. So where's the problem if my app's UI becomes unresponsive while the QR Code is being scanned?"
I am NOT asking why `java.lang.IllegalStateException` is thrown and I do NOT want callbacks.

Answer (score 0):

You should call the scanner.startScan() function from another suspend function to avoid it from getting executed on the main thread.

**Example :**
A barcode scanner class that has the function to start scan and store the result inside of a StateFlow.

```
class BarcodeScanner(
    context: Context
) {

    /**
     * From the docs: If you know which barcode formats you expect to read, you can improve the
     * speed of the barcode detector by configuring it to only detect those formats.
     */
    private val options = GmsBarcodeScannerOptions.Builder()
        .setBarcodeFormats(
            Barcode.FORMAT_ALL_FORMATS
        )
        .build()

    private val scanner = GmsBarcodeScanning.getClient(context, options)
    val barCodeResults = MutableStateFlow<String?>(null)

    suspend fun startScan() {
        try {
            val result = scanner.startScan().await()
            barCodeResults.value = result.rawValue
            Timber.d(barCodeResults.value)
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Log.d("scan error: $e")
        }
    }
```

**Provide the scanner class using dagger hilt**

```
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
@Module
object AppModules {

    @Provides
    fun provideBarcodeScanner(@ApplicationContext appContext: Context) = BarcodeScanner(appContext)

}
```

Call the function from your viewModel

```
class MainViewModel @Inject (barcodeScanner : BarcodeScanner) : ViewModel {

    val scanResult = MutableStateFlow<String?>(null)

    init{

      barcodeScanner.barCodeResults.collect{
              scanResult.value = it
         }
   }

    fun startScanning(){
        lifecycleScope.launch{
              barcodeScanner.startScan()           
        }
    }
}
```